# Show an array arrangement

Tags: c++

I am wanting to show an array arrangement with input for # of rows and # of columns and also insert a symbol at an input interval.I have this so far but my output only shows 1 row at a time until enter is pressed for how ever many rows were selected.  I haven't even started on the interval symbol insertion yet.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int rows = 0, columns = 0,intervals= 0;
void Display(int rows = 0, int columns = 0, int intervals = 0);

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin >> columns;

    cout << "Enter the number of the question mark interval: ";
    cin >> intervals;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "How many rows do you want? " << rows << "\n";
    cout << "How many columns do you want? " << columns << "\n";
    cout << "How far between question marks? " << intervals << "\n";

    Display(rows, columns, intervals);

    return(0);
    system("pause");
}

void Display(int rows, int columns, int intervals)
{
    for (int y = 1; y <= rows; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
            cout << intervals;
        }
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: is it because you have `system("pause");` after you complete printing each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `system("pause")` outside the loop -

```
void Display(int rows, int columns, int intervals)
{
    for (int y = 1; y <= rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
            cout << intervals;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: That's what happens when I stare at it too long. Ugly mistakes. Thank you.